# How does device mmap work in contrast to I/O address ports?

Tags: linux, memory-management, assembly, linux-kernel, kernel

I was wondering if Linux sees a difference between mmap to a peripheral devices memory in comparision to reading/writing to the device via I/O Ports. From what I've learned in my Assembly class, we pretty much looked at I/O port addressing in the same light as memory addressing. So I suppose I was wondering if I were to rw to  the I/O my port my device is connected to, is that the same thing mmaping to that devices memory?

Thanks

Comment: Very good description here: http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch09.pdf

Comment: Thanks, ya I am currently reading that particular book/pdf. I'm actually rushing through the material but I made it to chapter 15 which is what I'm on. I must have skipped part of chapter 9 and I should have read it more thoroughly, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I/O ports are not memory. Some hardware (e.g. graphical cards) are interfaced thru the memory bus, not only thru the I/O port bus.

For hardware having a memory interface (that is, viewed as a range of memory to the CPU), you might use `mmap`.

The X11 server `Xorg` is very often mmap-ing the graphical cards.

Comment: Ok, the memory bus that connects to ram is also shared by device memory like the graphics card ... if I understood correctly. So the devices have seperate i/o port and memory bus.

Answer (score 1):

I think the OP is confusing three things:

- mmap() is a way for application programs to perform some operations on  page registers and/or the MMU.
- Memory mapped I/O is a hardware architecture concept: instead of having separate buses and operations for I/O, some area of the address space is dedicated to I/O operations. (the 68K processor family uses memory mapped I/O, and IBM's AIX too, IIRC).
- DMA means that not only the CPU(s), but also the I/O devices can read and write to and from (parts of) *physical* memory.

Answer (score 0):

The `vm_area_struct` contains `vm_flags` field. In case of the special mapping it contains `VM_PFNMAP` or `VM_IO` flags. See struct [vm_area_struct](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.3.1/include/linux/mm_types.h#L194), [VM_PFNMAP](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.3.1/include/linux/mm.h#L90) and [VM_IO](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.3.1/include/linux/mm.h#L95) definitions at LXR.